# A conjugation of an operator, which commutes with all permutations, still commutes with all permutations

Tags: combinatorics, vector-spaces, operator-algebras, permutations

Assume $v:H^{\otimes m}\to H^{\otimes m}$ is a linear operator on the $n^{\text{th}}$ tensor power of a vector space $H$.
For each permutation $p$ on the $m$-element set define the linear operator $p:H^{\otimes m}\to H^{\otimes m}$ by $p(x_1\otimes \dots\otimes x_n)=(x_{p(1)}\otimes \dots\otimes x_{p(m)})$.

Now fix $n > m$ and let $1\leq j_1,\dots,j_m\leq n$ be two-by-two different and define the linear operator $V_{j_1,\dots,j_m}:H^{\otimes n}\to H^{\otimes n}$ by $V_{j_1,\dots,j_m}(x_1\otimes\dots\otimes x_n) = k_{j_1,\dots,j_m}^{-1}\circ (v\otimes Id \otimes \dots \otimes Id)\circ k_{j_1,\dots,j_m}$, where $k_{j_1,\dots,j_m}$ is the permutation operator that takes the elements in positions $j_1,\dots,j_m$ and puts them in the first $m$ positions in the same order.

**Proposition:** If $v$ commutes with each permutation operator then so does $V_{j_1,\dots,j_m}$.

**Thought:** Any permutation disjoint with $k_{j_1,\dots,j_m}$ commutes with $V$ because disjoint permutations commute. How can I get the general permutation to commute through?

**EDIT:** You may additionally assume that $j_i>j_k$ whenever $i>k$.

Comment: Might there be a typo in the definition of $V_{j_1,\ldots,j_m}$? The manner in which $v$ plays in isn't clear to me.

Comment: @JonathanY. $V_{j_1,\dots,j_m}$ is a sort of conjugation of $v$. Intuitively big $V$ makes little $v$ act on the components with indices $j_1,\dots,j_m$. I changed the "$1$" with "$Id$." I hope it makes more sense now.